# Data Persistence

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, data-persistence

When the app is loaded, I want to know whether I have already saved the data to disk. If it is saved, I just load from disk, if not, I save. 
for example, I want to save an array(person) using `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`

Save Method:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

 if let savedPeople = defaults.objectForKey("people") as? NSData 

     people = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedPeople) as! [Person]
```

But how can I know if I have saved the data or not in `viewDidLoad()`? I don't want to save every time I open the app, and it will also overwrite the data I modified before.

Comment: See if the file exists.

Comment: How to know it exists or not? can you give me a simple code to demonstrate. I am not so familiar with this part.

Comment: Look at NSFileManager

Comment: @rmaddy It sounds like he's using `NSUserDefaults` for persistence.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will do it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let savedPeople = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("people") {
        // Use savedPeople based on your need
    } else {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myArray, forKey: "people")
    }
}
```